# How can I update a value in record when the date/time match the date/time stored in the record itself

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have the following table

my_table

```
date | time | status
```

I need to change a status column from zero to one when the date and time match the date and time of the record which is specified by the user when he/she inserted the record.

When user choose date and time he/she will choose it depends on their time zone so how this will effect if the PHPMyAdmin use different time zone ?

The user will choose the date and time to change the status of the record, so initially the status will be 0 and once the date and time specified occur the status will be one.

Comment: Store date and time as a single entity.

Comment: OK even i do this, how i can then update the status of the record when the date/time match ?

Comment: Why would you need to store this value? Just construct your query to ignore events that happen in the past.

Comment: the user will choose the date and time to change the status of the record, so initially the status will be 0 and once the date and time specified occur the status will be one, got it ?

Comment: whatever code is using `status` should just compare the date/time instead, and you should delete the `status` column, because it's both derived and dynamic.

Comment: You should use `cron`